# Очереди и стеки в Java

Tags: java

Задали задание написать программу, в которой, имея строку, нужно сформировать очередь с парных символов и стек с каждого пятого символа. Я не очень сильна в этом, но сделала такую программу, но выдает не то, что надо (с массивом чисел все получается). Как переделать на строку? Помогите, буду очень признательна.

```
public class Node {
    private int inf;
    private Node next;

    Node() {
        inf=0;
        next=null;
    }
    Node(int i) {
        inf=i;
        next=null;
    }

    public void setInf(int i) {
        inf=i;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next=n;
    }

    public int getInf() {
        return inf;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }
}

public class List {
    private Node first;
    List() {
        first=null;
    }

    public void addFirstNode(Node n) {
        n.setNext(first);
        first=n;
    }

    public void addLastNode(Node n) {
        if (first==null) first=n;
        else {
            Node tmp=first;
            while (tmp.getNext()!=null) {
                tmp=tmp.getNext();
            }

            tmp.setNext(n);
        }
    }
    public void addFirst(int a) {
        Node newnode = new Node(a);
        addFirstNode(newnode);
    }

    public void addLast(int a) {
        Node newnode = new Node(a);
        addLastNode(newnode);
    }

    public void showList() {
        Node tmp=first;
        while (tmp!=null) {
            System.out.print(" "+tmp.getInf());
            tmp=tmp.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

package dom;

//основная программа

public class Dom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List queue = new List();
        List stack = new List();

        String s = "125478965321547896521547889633215478965487512546985478521";

        int l = s.length();
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if (i%2==0)
            {   char k=s.charAt(i);
                queue.addLast(k);
            }
            if (i%5==0)
            {   char k=s.charAt(i);
                stack.addFirst(k);
            }
        }

        queue.showList();
        stack.showList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

С выборкой вроде все в порядке... Проблема в выводе кодов вместо символов? Тогда храните в `Node#inf` значение `char`, а не `int`, или приводите к типу `char` в `showList()`:

```
System.out.print(" " + (char)tmp.getInf());
```

Только вы ж должны понимать, что реализованная вами структура не является ни [очередью](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29), ни [стеком](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA).

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что Вы храните **код** символа в стеке и очереди, т. к. у Вас структура хранит целый тип (число).

Чтобы всё заработало нужно преобразовать число в символ:

```
public void showList() {
    Node tmp = first;
    while( tmp != null ) {
        System.out.print(" "+ (char)tmp.getInf()); //здесь преобразование кода в символ
        tmp=tmp.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант: изменить тип поля inf в классе Node с int на Object. Соответсвенно изменятся getInf(), setInf(...) и конструктор, а также методы addLast(...) и addFirst(...) в классе List. Для целых чисел и символов это можно сделать, так как происходит автоматический wrapping/unwrapping в соответсвующие типы Integer и Character. Код вывода списка в консоль при этом не изменится: объекты пишутся через String.valueOf(...), для wrapper-классов это и будет значение числа/символа.

Вот участки кода, которые необходимо изменить:

```
//Node
private Object inf;
Node(Object inf){
    this.inf = inf;
    next = null;
}
public void setInf(Object inf){
    this.inf = inf;
}
public Object getInf(){
    return inf;
}

//List
public void addFirst(Object inf){
    Node newnode = new Node(inf);
    addFirstNode(newnode);
}
public void addLast(Object inf){
    Node newnode = new Node(inf);
    addLastNode(newnode);
}
```